# Google Speech to Text with OGG_OPUS

Tags: google-speech-api

Does the google speech to text API really support OGG_OPUS codec(for streaming audio)? I had no luck getting it to work. If anyone was able to get this working, can you please share any code snippets/suggestions? Basically the google API is not returning back any transcription results. Same issue with SPEEX codec...

Comment: Do you have code for Google Speech to text for another codec?